# Specifying path of android project in package.json (react-native)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Is there a way to specify android project path in react-native package.json file. By default the project lies in the same directory as the package.json, but what if the android project lies outside this directory? Is it even feasible to do so? I tried searching the official documentation of react-native, but was unable to find any relevant material there.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to do. Why do you want to specify an android project path in `package.json`?

Comment: Actually I want to add react-native module as a git submodule to my existing android project repo. The repo is quite old so I can't change the folder structure either.